# How to extract section of string from each string in factor vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a column with time stamps (that are classed as factors at the moment), that I'd like to extract from. There are about 220,000 rows and about half contain factors as "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" and the other half, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M". So about half have three more charters than the other half.

I'd like to extract from each row the, %d.%m.%Y %H:%M", leaving out the :%S from those that contain it.

Since they're classed as factors, my assumption is that they could be extracted by order, i.e. extract 1st - 14th charcter.

This is what the data looks like.

```
Start.Timestamp
01.01.2015 12:32
01.01.2015 08:22
01.01.2015 14:10
31.12.2014 21:43
01.01.2015 00:21
01.01.2015 12:38
01.01.2015 01:00
01.01.2015 14:13
01.01.2016 04:11:34
01.01.2016 10:13:30
01.01.2016 04:30:08
01.01.2016 08:49:40
01.01.2016 07:44:45
```

Also - all ":00" to those factors strings missing the "%S" would be acceptable.

I hope this is clear.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: First you have to convert to character: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: Maybe as `as.POSIXct(as.character(XXX$Start.Timestamp))` would help. There you can create any format you want with the preferred representation.

Comment: @drmariod I think this won't work. Expect an error message of the type "not in a standard unambiguous format".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your initial data is, something like:

```
lapply(df,substring, first=1, last=16)
```

could maybe help.

When your data is like this:

```
df <- data.frame("Start.Timestamp",
             "01.01.2015 12:32",
             "01.01.2015 08:22",
             "01.01.2015 14:10",
             "31.12.2014 21:43",
             "01.01.2015 00:21",
             "01.01.2015 12:38",
             "01.01.2015 01:00",
             "01.01.2015 14:13",
             "01.01.2016 04:11:34",
             "01.01.2016 10:13:30",
             "01.01.2016 04:30:08",
             "01.01.2016 08:49:40",
             "01.01.2016 07:44:45")

lapply(df,substring, first=1, last=16)
#$X.Start.Timestamp.
#[1] "Start.Timestamp"

#$X.01.01.2015.12.32.
#[1] "01.01.2015 12:32"

#$X.01.01.2015.08.22.
#[1] "01.01.2015 08:22"

#$X.01.01.2015.14.10.
#[1] "01.01.2015 14:10"

#$X.31.12.2014.21.43.
#[1] "31.12.2014 21:43"

...
```

Or any other of the apply functions, as I do not know how your whole data is set up.

Comment: The function `substring()` is vectorized. A `*apply()` loop is unnecessarily slow and complicated in this case.  You can use `substring(df$Start.Timestamp, first=1, last=16)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a factor column, I would recommend converting it to a vector of characters and using both `strptime()` and `strftime()` to get the desired output in a datetime format:

#### Your vector in a data.frame

```
your_df <- structure(list(Start.Timestamp = structure(c(4L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 10L), .Label = c("01.01.2015 00:21", 
"01.01.2015 01:00", "01.01.2015 08:22", "01.01.2015 12:32", "01.01.2015 12:38", 
"01.01.2015 14:10", "01.01.2015 14:13", "01.01.2016 04:11:34", 
"01.01.2016 04:30:08", "01.01.2016 07:44:45", "01.01.2016 08:49:40", 
"01.01.2016 10:13:30", "31.12.2014 21:43"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Start.Timestamp", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

#### Getting your desired output:

```
strftime(strptime(as.character(your_df$Start.Timestamp), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

#### Output

```
 [1] "01.01.2015 12:32" "01.01.2015 08:22" "01.01.2015 14:10" "31.12.2014 21:43" "01.01.2015 00:21"
 [6] "01.01.2015 12:38" "01.01.2015 01:00" "01.01.2015 14:13" "01.01.2016 04:11" "01.01.2016 10:13"
[11] "01.01.2016 04:30" "01.01.2016 08:49" "01.01.2016 07:44"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use lubridate's `dmy_hms()` function with the option `truncated = 1` to generate a POSIXct object. This option is helpful when the time data has incomplete entries, like missing seconds in this case (which are then set to 00).

The output of `dmy_hms()` can then be wrapped into `format()` to obtain the desired form:

```
format(lubridate::dmy_hms(df1$Start.Timestamp, truncated = 1),"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
# [1] "01.01.2015 12:32" "01.01.2015 08:22" "01.01.2015 14:10" "31.12.2014 21:43"
# [5] "01.01.2015 00:21" "01.01.2015 12:38" "01.01.2015 01:00" "01.01.2015 14:13"
# [9] "01.01.2016 04:11" "01.01.2016 10:13" "01.01.2016 04:30" "01.01.2016 08:49"
#[13] "01.01.2016 07:44"
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Start.Timestamp = structure(c(4L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 10L), .Label = c("01.01.2015 00:21", 
"01.01.2015 01:00", "01.01.2015 08:22", "01.01.2015 12:32", "01.01.2015 12:38", 
"01.01.2015 14:10", "01.01.2015 14:13", "01.01.2016 04:11:34", 
"01.01.2016 04:30:08", "01.01.2016 07:44:45", "01.01.2016 08:49:40", 
"01.01.2016 10:13:30", "31.12.2014 21:43"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = "Start.Timestamp", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: thank you for the input!! This did the trick without any problems and helped me move along to count the correct number of instances per hour over the study period!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the given format (dput a sample of your data). One possibility was

```
> str <- c("01.01.2016 07:44", "01.01.2016 07:45")
> substr(str, 1,16)
[1] "01.01.2016 07:44" "01.01.2016 07:45"
```

if truncation is ok.